# Creating PageControl with ScrollViews without using Interace Builder

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'd like to have a `PageControl` for a series of `UIScrollViews`, but don't want to use the Interface Builder (reason 1: to really understand how it works, reason 2: don't like Interface Builder) but can't find an example **without** nibs. Anyone an idea where i could find such an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 396, 200, 36)];
pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```